# How can i record a video from webcam(using Angular 4) and send it to back-end(Spring-boot)?

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I am using angular 4 and spring in my project.
I want to access the webcam and record the video, and send it to the back end for storing that video.Is it possible because I searched on the web nothing useful there for me and also I want to record voice from accessing the mic and send it to back end.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this question? If you did I would be interested in hearing it.

Comment: I think recordRTC Solves the problem... as I am trying to integrate into my application...